# How to pass data from radio button and rerender?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

Please find my below code need to pass data as radio button rather than command link.

Radio button should be in multi select !

```
<apex:page controller="update_random_question" showHeader="f">
    {!count}
    <apex:form >    
    <div align="center" draggable="false" >    
     <apex:Commandbutton Value="Begin" action="{!update_random_question}" reRender="Questions_Block"/>
    </div> 
     <apex:pageBlock Id="Questions_Block" >
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!question_list}" var="q">
          <apex:column value="{!q.QuestionName__c}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!answer_list}" var="a">

             <apex:column >
            <apex:commandLink value="{!a.AnswerName__c}" action="{!is_answer}" reRender="CheckAnswer" >    
                 <apex:param name="idParam" value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!idchosen}" />
            </apex:commandLink>               
             </apex:column>          

         </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>

     <apex:pageBlock id="CheckAnswer">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CheckAnswerlist}" var="an">
              <apex:column value="{!an.IsAnswer__c}"/>
          </apex:pageblockTable>
     <div align="right" draggable="false" >
     <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">
       <apex:Commandbutton Value="ShowAnswer" action="{!show_answer}" reRender="show_answer"/>
       <apex:Commandbutton Value="Next" action="{!updateanswer}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     </div>
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ShowAnswerlist}" var="an" id="show_answer">
          <apex:column headerValue="" value="{!an.AnswerName__c}"/>
      </apex:pageblockTable>

     </apex:pageBlock>                
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex:**

```
public class update_random_question
{
    public String is_answer {get; set;}
    public List<Question__c> question_list{get;set;}
    public List<Answer__c> answer_list{get;set;}
    public List<Answer__c> CheckAnswerlist{get;set;}
    public List<Answer__c> ShowAnswerlist{get;set;}
    public string idchosen{get;set;}
    public integer count {get;set;}

    public pagereference update_random_question()
    {
        question_list= [SELECT Name,QuestionName__c,orderby__c FROM Question__c];
        for(Question__c q : question_list)
        {
            q.iscompleted__c = False;
            q.orderby__c = randomizer.getRandomNumber(1000);            
        }
        answer_list= [SELECT Name,AnswerName__c,orderby__c FROM Answer__c];
        for(answer__c a : answer_list)
        {
            a.orderby__c = randomizer.getRandomNumber(1000);            
        }
    update question_list;
    update answer_list;

    question_list = [SELECT Id,Q_id__c,Name,QuestionName__c,OrderBy__c FROM question__c where iscompleted__c = False order by Name limit 1];

    answer_list = [SELECT Name,AnswerName__c,OrderBy__c From Answer__c WHERE Q_id__c = :question_list[0].Q_id__c order by Name];

    if(ShowAnswerlist!=null && !ShowAnswerlist.isEmpty()) {
    ShowAnswerlist.clear();
    }
    if(CheckAnswerlist!=null && !CheckAnswerlist.isEmpty()) {
    CheckAnswerlist.clear();
    }

    count= database.countQuery('SELECT count() FROM question__c where iscompleted__c = False');       
    return null;
    }

    public void is_answer()
    {
      CheckAnswerlist = [SELECT isanswer__c From Answer__c WHERE id = :idchosen];
    }

    public void updateanswer()
    {
        if(ShowAnswerlist!=null && !ShowAnswerlist.isEmpty()) {
        ShowAnswerlist.clear();
        }
        if(CheckAnswerlist!=null && !CheckAnswerlist.isEmpty()) {
        CheckAnswerlist.clear();
        }

       if(question_list!=null && !question_list.isEmpty()) {
       question_list[0].iscompleted__c = TRUE;
       update question_list;

    question_list = [SELECT Id,Q_id__c,Name,QuestionName__c,OrderBy__c FROM question__c where iscompleted__c = False order by Name limit 1];


    answer_list = [SELECT Name,AnswerName__c,OrderBy__c From Answer__c WHERE Q_id__c = :question_list[0].Q_id__c order by Name];

    }

    count= database.countQuery('SELECT count() FROM question__c where iscompleted__c = False');

    }
    public void show_answer()
    {

    if(ShowAnswerlist!=null && !ShowAnswerlist.isEmpty()) {
    ShowAnswerlist.clear();
    }
    if(CheckAnswerlist!=null && !CheckAnswerlist.isEmpty()) {
    CheckAnswerlist.clear();
    }

    question_list = [SELECT Id,Q_id__c,Name,QuestionName__c,OrderBy__c FROM question__c where iscompleted__c = False order by Name limit 1];

    ShowAnswerlist = [SELECT Name,AnswerName__c,OrderBy__c From Answer__c WHERE Q_id__c = :question_list[0].Q_id__c AND Isanswer__c = TRUE order by Name];    

    }
}
```

Comment: What is this not doing that you're expecting it to do? Is the method being called but not the rerender?

Comment: screen shots would be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select more than one value, then you MUST use selectList as selectRadio does NOT allow more than one selection.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selItem}" multiselect="true">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/></apex:selectList>
```

where:

- items - is the list of values you want to populate the SelectList with
- selItem - the value thats gets set on the field(controller)